# How to recursively compare a string to a list of the alphabet and return the value from a different list, on the same index

Tags: python, arrays, list

**Update**:
Sorry for the late reply, but thanks again for your help. I think I've somehow managed to write it the way I'm expected to, but I get a ValueError on: `m = ciphertext.index(n)` Does anyone see if I've made a mistake?

```
def cipher (message: str, ciphertext: list, alphabet: list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]) -> str:

    if len(message) == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        n = alphabet.index(message[0])
        m = ciphertext.index(n)
        message = message[1:]
        return m + cipher(message, ciphertext)

        
ciphertext = ["C", "D", "E", "F",  "G", "H", "I",  "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B"]
message = "Hello"

print(cipher(message, ciphertext))
```

**Old**:
So, I'm supposed to write a function for a substitution cipher in Python. I input a message, the function compares it to a list of the alphabet, and recursively returns the corresponding letter from a second list, on the same index.

I'm given this code to start with, but I have no idea how to find the same index of the other list, or how to write it recursively to have it continue rewriting each letter of the message until it reaches len(message) == 0.

```
def cipher (message: str, ciphertext: list, alphabet: list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]) -> str:

if len(message) == 0:
    return ""
else:
```

The function shall return a new text with the same size as the original, except that each letter has been replaced by the corresponding letter in the ciphertext according to its position. For example:

Alphabet=  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",  "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

Sample ciphertext alphabet = ["C", "D", "E", "F",  "G", "H", "I",  "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B"]

Sample message = "EXAMPLE"

Sample return ciphertext= "GZCORNG"

Any help is appreciated. Python is very new to me, so if you can help, please use simple terms/methods.

Comment: A `recursive` function is a function which calls itself. The question that you ask does not require a recursive function, but in fact something like a `dict` would be more appropriate (and faster).  It might be useful if you add a bit more code.

Comment: There are probably more efficient ways to solve it, but unfortunately the task requires me to solve it with a recursive function.

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. What have you tried so far? Tests are given for a reason

Comment: I would add that a list is in fact a dictionary whose {`key`, `value`} pairs are {`integers`, `list_values`} which is why a list can be `enumerated`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code:

```
def cipher (message: str, ciphertext: list, alphabet: list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]) -> str:

    if len(message) == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        n = alphabet.index(message[0])
        m = ciphertext[n]
        message = message[1:]
        return m + cipher(message, ciphertext)

        
ciphertext = ["C", "D", "E", "F",  "G", "H", "I",  "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B"]
message = "Hello"
message = message.upper()

print(cipher(message, ciphertext))
```

I note a similar answer spotting the same two bugs.

1. m = ciphertext[n]
2. message = message.upper()

Note the difference, here i leave `message = message.upper()` outside of the function since it is recursive. (it would be inefficient converting to capitals repeatedly).

The return of the 'hello' input with the given cypher is:

```
JGNNQ
```

Comment: You are welcome. stackoverflow is a great community of intelligence and glad to be part of that.  As a side note, i ran both codes 1000 times and the first method (with the dicts) are approximately twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starter that works.

```
# the cypher to be used (as a dictionary)
cypher_code = {
    'a':'a', 'b':'c', 'c':'f', 'd':'f', 'e':'g',
    'f':'a', 'g':'c', 'h':'f', 'i':'f', 'j':'g',
    'k':'a', 'l':'c', 'm':'f', 'n':'f', 'o':'g',
    'p':'a', 'q':'c', 'r':'f', 's':'f', 't':'g',    
    'u':'a', 'v':'c', 'w':'f', 'x':'f', 'y':'g', 'z':'a'
    }

def cipher (message: str, cypher_to_use: dict) -> str:
    ''' function to encrypt / decrypt'''
    
    if len(message) == 0:
        return ''


    decoded_word = ''
    for letter in message:
        decoded_letter = cypher_to_use[letter]
        decoded_word = decoded_word + decoded_letter

    return decoded_word

x = cipher('hello', cypher_code)
print(x)
```

converts `hello` to `fgccg`.

Hope this helps !

Comment: It works nicely, thanks for that. It certainly points me in the right direction, but unfortunately I'm not supposed to use for-loops or dict for this task, as we've yet to learn it... Is there a more basic way to go about this?

Comment: the loop is used to iterate through each letter in the list. You could step through a `linked list` (such as this:  https://realpython.com/linked-lists-python), but it would initially be more complicated.

Comment: one can remove the for loop with list comprehension `decoded_word = ''.join([cypher_to_use[letter] for letter in message])`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, though your tips are a bit above my skill level at the moment. If it's not too much to ask, could you take a quick look at my code? I've updated my post with what I've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two bugs, You missed case conversion and were using `ciphertext.index[n]` where you meant `ciphertext[n]`

```
def cipher (message: str, ciphertext: list, alphabet: list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]) -> str:
        message = message.upper()
        if len(message) == 0:
            return ""
        else:
            n = alphabet.index(message[0])
            m = ciphertext[n]
            message = message[1:]
            return m + cipher(message, ciphertext)
    ciphertext = ["C", "D", "E", "F",  "G", "H", "I",  "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B"]
    message = "Hello"
    print(cipher(message, ciphertext))
```

Comment: I really should've spotted the case conversion, but I thought 'ciphertext.index[n]' was correct. Thanks for pointing that out, I wouldn't have caught that. Thanks for helping this newbie out!

Comment: Welcome :) the index method of a list object returns the index of the passed object in the list, if any.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you could refine this further to preserve the case of the original message.

```
def cipher (message: str, ciphertext: list, alphabet: list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]) -> str:
    if len(message) == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        first_letter  = message[0]
        n = alphabet.index(first_letter.upper())
        m = ciphertext[n]
        message = message[1:]
        return (m if first_letter.isupper() else m.lower()) + cipher(message, ciphertext)

        
ciphertext = ["C", "D", "E", "F",  "G", "H", "I",  "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B"]
message = "Hello"

print(cipher(message, ciphertext))
```

`"Hello`" transforms to `"Jgnnq"`