# Python encrypt code from particular line until the end

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I want to encrypt a code from a particular line until a line in python 3.x . The reason I am requesting it in this manner because my code has to get user input form in that same code.

example of code will be like this
name: something
place: Germany
age: 20

####variables end here###

codes start from here:
print(name)
print(place)
print(age)

so what I wanted is the codes to be encrypted/obfuscated or unreadable to users. The only exception is the variables that has to be readable to user.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a place to ask us to write codes for you.

Comment: I am not asking for codes . I am asking if there is any module to encrypt.

Comment: i answered an encryption question here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243224/how-to-recursively-compare-a-string-to-a-list-of-the-alphabet-and-return-the-val?noredirect=1#comment125931640_71243224